# Правильно ли составлено предложение по смыслу и пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, орфография, синтаксис, сложное-предложение

> Старая женщина извечно носившая одну и ту же одежду: чёрное, сильно
> заношенное винтажное платье; шёлковый, засаленный чёрный платок;
> бесформенные туфли в тон к платку и платью - сильно пугала Сергея.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно обособить причастный оборот:

*Старая женщина, **извечно носившая одну и ту же одежду**:  чёрное, сильно заношенное винтажное платье; шёлковый, засаленный чёрный платок; бесформенные туфли в тон к платку и платью, – сильно пугала Сергея.*

Comment: Перед тире не хотите поставить запятую, закрыть оборот?

Comment: Поставлю, пожалуй, спасибо.  Хотелось бы в  правилах посмотреть на оформление подобных предложений. Вам попадались такие примеры?

Comment: Именно такие нет. Но у Розенталя: "Если по условиям контекста после однородных членов предложения требуется постановка запятой, то она ставится..." То есть однородные члены с обобщающим словом находятся внутри обособленного оборота.

Comment: Мне бы хотелось найти пример именно с обобщающим словом и рядом. Меня вообще эта тема интересует, в разных вариантах. Например: "Наряду с иными стихийными бедствиями, как-то: пожар, град, начисто выбивающий хлебные поля, ненастье или, наоборот, великая сушь, есть в деревне еще одно бедствие... (Солоухин)  https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=69764&p=31  Здесь тире нет, но в правилах Розенталя оно поставлено (пункт 8) http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103  Поэтому эта тема мне не до конца понятна.